# wxButtonClick don't give a sign of being alife

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Yesterday, I have posted a question on `Creating a pointer to a widget in a function`, after I  compiled the program and tried to use it, but when I click on the button, nothing happens.

Maybe, somewhere know where my failure is, or know some improvement of my code, that just can help. My code:

**gui.h**

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <string>

class wxWCK : public wxFrame
{
public:
    wxWCK(const wxString& title);

    void OnClickCon(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnClickSta(wxCommandEvent& event);

private:
    wxButton *connect;
    wxButton *start;
    wxTextCtrl *text;
};

const int ID_CON = wxID_HIGHEST + 1;
const int ID_STA = wxID_HIGHEST + 2;
const int ID_MF0 = 102;
const int ID_TEX = 103;

void Connect();
void Start();
```

**gui.cpp**

```
#include "gui.h"

wxWCK::wxWCK(const wxString& title)
    : wxFrame(NULL, ID_MF0, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(400,300))
{
    wxPanel *panel = new wxPanel(this, -1);

    wxBoxSizer *vbox  = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    wxBoxSizer *hbox1 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    wxBoxSizer *hbox2 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);   

    //Outputwidget
    text = new wxTextCtrl(panel, ID_TEX, _T(""), 
        wxPoint(-1, -1), wxSize(1000, 1000), wxTE_MULTILINE);

    //redirecting stream to the outputwidget
    std::ostream stream(text);  
    stream << "Hello" << std::endl;

    connect = new wxButton(panel, ID_CON, _T("Connect"));
    start   = new wxButton(panel, ID_STA, _T("Start"));

    hbox1->Add(text);
    hbox2->Add(connect);
    hbox2->Add(start);

    vbox->Add(hbox1, 1, wxEXPAND);
    vbox->Add(hbox2, 0, wxALIGN_LEFT | wxRIGHT | wxBOTTOM, 10);

    panel->SetSizer(vbox);

    Connect(ID_CON, wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED,
        wxCommandEventHandler(wxWCK::OnClickCon));
    //Connect(ID_STA, wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED,
    //  wxCommandEventHandler(wxWCK::OnClickSta));
}

void wxWCK::OnClickCon(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{   void Connect(); }

void wxWCK::OnClickSta(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{   void Start();   }

void Connect()
{
    //Try to get a pointer to 'text'
    std::ostream stream((wxTextCtrl*) wxWindow::FindWindowById(ID_TEX));
    std::string con = "Connected";
    stream << con << std::endl;
}

void Start()
{
    //Try to get a pointer to 'text'
    std::ostream stream((wxTextCtrl*) wxWindow::FindWindowById(ID_TEX));
    std::string sta = "Started";
    stream << sta << std::endl;
}
```

*I'm using wxWidgets 2.9.4, the g++-Compiler and CodeLite 5.1*

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40164/should-we-close-fix-my-program-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void wxWCK::OnClickCon(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{   void Connect(); }
```

Replace with:

```
void wxWCK::OnClickCon(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{   Connect(); }
```

Make forward declaration of `Connect` function before `OnClickCon` if necessary. Fix `OnClickSta` function by the same way.

Comment: Thx, you are great! I had to make the function-prototyp in the Ctor so that the Onclick-Fct know the to calling functions.